# List Manager considers 2 entries with same first and last name, same contact

Tags: exm, list-manager

I tried to use EXM and upload CSV file which contains first name, last name and Email for two contacts with the same first name and last name but 2 different mails.

Sitecore considers them as they are one contact....is that Sitecore issue?!! and if I want to add configuration to be 2 contacts not one...how can I make that?!!

*Copied from OP's comment:*

I tried to use EXM with "Regular email campaign" and upload csv file with two contacts with the same first and last name and different emails but after finishing and mapping fields I found that "Contacts expected to be imported is 1"

Comment: Which Sitecore version? Have you selected email to be used as identifier?

Comment: I use sitecore version 9.1.....how can I make email be as identifier?!

Comment: Do you use `List Manager` app to create new list from CSV? It should use email as identifier by default. How do you know Sitecore considers contacts with different emails as the same contact?

Comment: I tried to use EXM with "Regular email campaign" and upload csv file with two contacts with the same first and last name and different emails but after finishing and mapping fields I found that "Contacts expected to be imported is 1"

Comment: Try list manager and creation of list from CSV first and then using that list in regular mail

Comment: Comment converted into an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of importing contacts during email creation, use List Manager application to create a list from a csv file first:

[image]

And then make sure you map your csv columns properly:

[image]